# PHP While Statements with SQLSRV Query

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I have the following PHP code:

```
echo "var s1 = [";
$count = 0;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
  if ($count++ > 0) echo ", ";
  echo $row['OrdersBal'];
  }
echo "];\n";
echo "var ticks = [";
$count2 = 0;
while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
  if ($count2++ > 0) echo ", ";
  echo "'" . $row2['CardName'] . "'";
  }         
echo "];\n";
```

It's currently outputting:

```
var s1 = [37966.550000, 19876.170000, 17314.580000, 15614.410000, 7575.000000];
var ticks = [];
```

But I want it to output:

```
var s1 = [37966.550000, 19876.170000, 17314.580000, 15614.410000, 7575.000000];
var ticks = ['Parameter Technology', 'Earthshaker Corporation', 'Microchips', 'Mashina Corporation', 'SG Electronics'];
```

If I move the second while statement so that it occurs first then that statement will output correctly. This has lead me to believe that I can't execute two while statements in a row in this fashion, but I'm not sure what my alternatives are. Thanks for any help!

Comment: 1 loop, 1 count, 2 strings

Comment: @hsuk, please don't just go through adding tags to questions. Please fix everything.

Comment: okay, thank you for your suggestion. I won't do it anymore.

Comment: It's fine to add good tags @hsuk, just if there's anything else you can see to change then please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use variables to store text during loop and then print them out:

```
$count = 0;
$orders = "";
$cardNames = "";
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if ($count++ > 0)
    {
        $orders .= ", ";
        $cardNames .= ", ";
    }
    $orders .= $row['OrdersBal'];
    $cardNames .= $row['CardName'];
}

echo "var s1 = [" . $orders . "];\n";
echo "var ticks = [" . $cardNames . "];\n";
```